# auto-wrapping for ObservableCollection elements

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection

as title says, i'm trying to implement auto-wrapping of ObservableCollection items, currently i'm doing it using CollectionChanged event, where i check if element is of required type and if not, i create object of this type (which is a container as well), move element to it and try to replace current element in collection by the wrapper, but here i get run-time error that ObservableCollection cannot be modified during CollectionChanged event, so, my question is, how to implement auto-wrapping?
here is the example code:

```
[ContentProperty("Items")]
public partial class BaseUserControl : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Items",
        typeof(ObservableCollection<FrameworkElement>), typeof(BaseUserControl));
    public ObservableCollection<FrameworkElement> Items
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<FrameworkElement>)GetValue(ItemsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemsProperty, value); }
    }

    public BaseUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Items.CollectionChanged += Items_CollectionChanged;
    }

    private void Items_CollectionChanged(object? sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <  Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (Items[i] is not WrapperUserControl)
            {
                WrapperUserControl wrapper = new WrapperUserControl();
                wrapper.Items.Add(Items[i]);
                Items[i] = wrapper;
                return;
            }
        }

        // do something else
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i get run-time error that ObservableCollection cannot be modified during CollectionChanged event

This error only occurs when more than one handler is listening the `CollectionChanged` event, so if possible, do not expose the `ObservableCollection` property. You can encapsulate a `CollectionChanged` event to the desired listener.

```
public partial class BaseUserControl : UserControl
{
    ....

    public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler? CollectionChanged;

    private void Items_CollectionChanged(object? sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ....
        CollectionChanged?.Invoke(sender, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: short and brilliant. point 1: i was wandering why in my other auto-wrapping system this error was not being thrown, that's why lol; point 2: by design i should've had only 1 handler for each collectionChanged event, but thanks to you i found a bug where i subscribe unnecessary handler to this event of a collection which is actually already used because of the binding; point 3: sadly i can't encapsulate it as the collection is target of ContentProperty and should be visible outside, but still a useful hack to remember for the future cases. Thank you.